# how to print the input data and errors in the node shell in corda

Tags: blockchain, corda

Let us consider the IOU project. when we start the ExampleFlow we provide some input in the flow and those input can be tracked in the log file but want we want to display that input in the node shell also after the transaction.
Like when a contract fail the node shell show that some RPC error is their but if you go to log file you will see that you have given iouValue grater then 100 this same error massage we want to display in the node shell can i do it if yes then how if no then why not.

Answer (score 0):

To have full control of the response, you need to implement an RPC client, or a webserver; below are samples for both:
**RPC Client:** https://github.com/corda/samples/tree/release-V4/cordapp-example/clients
**Webserver:** https://github.com/corda/samples/tree/release-V4/spring-webserver